Change of variables along vertical strip
I'm working on an integral involving multiple Hankel transforms. After the integrating over the Bessel functions, I'm left with a double integral over the region $\mathcal{R}= \{x,y:|x-y|<1<x+y\}.$ This can be easily transformed to a vertical strip by setting $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, leaving
$$
\int_\mathcal{R}f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{u\geq1}\int_{-1<v<1}g(u,v),
$$
where $g(u(x,y),v(x,y))=f(x,y)$, and
$$
f(x,y)=e^{-\alpha x^2}x^{a-1}e^{-\beta y^2}y^{b-1}\left((1-(x-y)^2)((x+y)^2-1)\right)^{c-1}
$$
Now, the explicit form of $g(u,v)$ is rife with quantities like $u^2-1$, $v^2-1$, and $u\pm v$. Coupled with the range of integration, this seems to imply some substitution involving hyperbolic trigonometric functions that will simplify things greatly. Of course, there is the obvious $v=\tanh(s)$, $u=\cosh(t)$ with $0\leq t$ and $-\infty<s<\infty$, but that certainly doesn't simplify much, because the arguments of the hyperbolic functions are independent, and introducing a radial variable instead of a second angle precludes any simplification of the function through trigonometric identities.
Is there a change of variables along this vein of reasoning that does indeed allow for simplification through trigonometric identities?

What's the definition of $f(x,y)$?

I updated the question to include $f(x,y)$.

Have you tried the change of variables $v=\tanh⁡(\phi)$ and $u=\cosh⁡(t)$? this might simplify the integral by turning factors like $1−v^2$ and $u^2−1$ into hyperbolic trigonometric expressions.

@y9QQ, any constraints on $a,b,c$?

Ideally, I'd like to treat $a$ and $b$ as integers greater than zero and $c$ as a positive real, but in principle the result should hold for all positive reals, possibly for all reals (barring a finite number of poles). Also, $c$ should be continuable to $\mathbb{C}$. I've solved this problem for many combinations of $a, b$, and $c$, and they always end up in gamma functions or as hypergeometric parameters. These other solutions also lead me to believe that the general solution will be related to confluent hypergeometric functions (not necessarily Tricomi/Kummer, perhaps a higher ${}pF{p}$.

Either that, or the Fourier transform is related to confluent hypergeometric fucntions in some way.

@DrPotato: Yes, that was my first thought, as noted in the question. Under this transformation, the problems are then moved to the $u\pm v$ bits, which are not thereafter tractable in any way I can recognize. I have also tried similar transformations with different linear combinations of the hyperbolic angles as arguments within the hyperbolic functions, hoping to use trig. identities to simplify the problematic factors... no luck though.

@Srini: I'm sorry, $a$ and $b$ should be negative integers. I have them written differently in my notes, and I confused my variables. Additionally, I'm certain that you can treat $x^p$ as $(x^2)^{p/2}$ for whatever $p$ may be and likewise for $y$, if that helps (maybe for a differentiation trick or similar).
